# how to close ng-template by id in angular?

Tags: angular, ng-template

We have a model popup, inside we have a ng-template dialog for dropdown selection. After selecting a value from the drop-down we need to close only the ng-template dialog but the parent model popup should still be open unless it is manually closed by the user. The issue that is happening is that when the ng-template dialog is closed then it closes the parent model popup also.

We are expecting that the 'parent model popup' should not be closed on it's own when ng-template dialog is closed.

Comment: what do you use to display the dialog and dropdown? Angular Material CDK?

Comment: share a working code over stackblitz to see what is there in the cde

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.